# Open TCP Port, Service Listening, Yet Connection Refused

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I'm trying to port forward so I can host servers for my friends. I'm using a Minecraft server as it's simple to setup and run. My PC is at 192.168.1.104 and the server is set on the port 25565 at 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0:25565). I've checked using "netstat -a" in the CMD and the server shows up as listening. Yet, when I try to check if my port is open via a website or program, it says it's closed and gives the vague "Connection Refused" message. I've been messing around with it for many hours. I have added an inbound and outbound rule for my server port, as well as tried to connect with the firewall disabled completely. I DO NOT have any other AV software besides Defender, which I have disabled.

Edit: My router is a Linksys WRT54G2. It has a tab for Apps & Games, which includes a port forwarding tab and QoS. My start and end are set to 25565, UDP and TCP (Both), and my port is set to 104 (Local PC).

Edit (2): telnet seems to work, but there's no output, but I'd imagine there wouldn't be anyways.

Comment: You did not say anything about the port forwarding configuration you did in your router. What is your router and how did you configure it?

Comment: At the end you say the port is set to 104.  I assume you mean "IP Address" is 104 in the router config?  Also, if your PC is 104 now, have you statically set the IP to 104.  If the IP is obtained from the DHCP service running on the router then this could change in the future.  If this is a permanent setup, you may want to statically set your IP on the PC.  This shouldn't matter now, I assume 104 is still correct.  Do you have another PC on the local network.  You could try running `telnet 192.169.1.104 25565`.  This should "connect" and would at least prove that the PC is open to connections.

Comment: There is another computer on the network, but it doesn't really do anything.